# Custom sort not working after filtering in PrimeNG table

Tags: angular, sorting, filter, primeng, primeng-turbotable

Custom sorting and filtering work fine individually, but after applying a local filter, the custom sorting doesn't work. On printing the sorting output on the console it gives the expected output, but the same isn't being updated on the frontend.

Here is the stackblitz implementation to the issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ot8vny?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import SortEvent

```
import { SortEvent } from 'primeng/api';
```

Then change the sort function to this:

```
onSorting(event: SortEvent) {
    event.data.sort((d1, d2) => {
      let v1 = d1[event.field];
      let v2 = d2[event.field];
      return event.order === -1 ? v1.localeCompare(v2) : v2.localeCompare(v1);
    });
  }
```

You need to use `event.data` to sort.